# How to draw disappearing rectangles in Java

Tags: java

I want to make a program in Java. What I am trying to do is, when the user click the screen a small square is drawn. One by one ten more squares are displayed with the previous square in the center. When the sixth square is drawn the first disappears, when the seventh square is drawn the second square disappears etc. until all the squares are gone.

This is the MainActivity:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainActivity {
    public static int width = 900;
    public static int height = width / 16 * 9;

    static HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();

    static JFrame window;
    static JPanel windowInner;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        window = new JFrame("Squarmony 1.0");
        window.setSize(width, height);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        windowInner = new JPanel();
        windowInner.setSize(width, height);
        windowInner.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        window.add(windowInner);
        windowInner.addMouseListener(handler);
    }

    private static class HandlerClass implements MouseListener {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            GraphicsActivity g = new GraphicsActivity();
            g.drawRectRipple(window.getGraphics(), e);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
}
```

And here is the GraphicsActivity:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class GraphicsActivity {
    public void drawRectRipple(Graphics g, MouseEvent e) {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 250; j += 10) {
                g.drawRect(e.getX() + j / 2, e.getY() - j / 2, j - j / 2, j + j / 2);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(250);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How could I draw the rectangles one by one (like ripples) to the screen?

Thanks,

John

Comment: You mean you have some homework you need done?

Comment: Put the rectangles in a fixed-length queue.

Comment: This isn't homework. It is just something that I wanted to try.

Comment: Show us What have you tried?

Comment: Sorry but I can't believe for a second this isn't homework.

Comment: This site is a **Questions & Answers** site, people are supposed to supply questions and other people provide answers.  There is no actual question here.

Comment: Sorry. My bad. I've made it a question now.

Comment: Also, I don't take any computer classes of any sorts. This is just a project that I'm doing for myself.

Comment: This is fun question, but I'm about to run out. Start by taking a lo at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for starters. Basically, I would use a javax.swing.Timer and some kind of counter to form the bases for the animation...

Comment: Cheers for the tips. I'll look into them and let you know how it works out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are probably a number of ways to achieve this, some easier, some harder.

Backgound:

Animation is the illusion of change over time.  This means over a time period, some kind of change is expected to happen.  In your case, some squares get painted, some don't.

Now, this suggests that we need some way to update our UI on a regular bases.  Now you could use a `Thread`, but to be frank, there are easier ways.

Swing provides a `Timer` class that provides events on a regular time interval, this allows us to make changes to the UI safely from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

This is important, because it is expected that all updates and modifications to the UI occur within the context of the EDT.  Also, any action which blocks the EDT will prevent the UI from being updated.  Check out [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Now, you could set a timer to tick at a predefined interval that meets your needs.  Ie, you need 10 updates over a period of *n* seconds, but this begins to put you at a slight disadvantage, as all you calculations would be based on some known, concert value...While you can certainly do this, I prefer a more flexible solution.

So, instead, I've chosen to use a "percentage" based approach.  That is, all my animation is based on knowing that at given percentage of the way through the cycle, something needs to happen.  This makes it possible to have a variable time frame without adversely effecting the paint algorithm.

To achieve this, we need to know when the cycle started and how long the cycle is.  This way we can calculate the duration a cycle has being running and the percentile of the cycle that is completed, for example

```
Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Check to see if the cycle has being completed...
        if (cycleStartedAt == -1) {
            // The time that this cycle started
            cycleStartedAt = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        // The amount of time this cycle has being running
        long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - cycleStartedAt;
        // The progress through this cycle...
        progress = (double)duration / (double)runningTime;
        // Check for the completion of this cycle...
        if (progress > 1.0d) {
            // Reset..
            cycleStartedAt = -1;
            progress = 0;
        }
        repaint();
    }
});
timer.setRepeats(true);
timer.start();
```

What does this actually provide us?  The provides us the ability to model the animation based on percentage of time.  For example...

```
private double[][] squares = {
    {0, 0.30},
    {0.075, 0.375},
    {0.15, 0.45},
    {0.225, 0.525},
    {0.30, 0.60},

    {0.30, 0.675},
    {0.375, 0.75},
    {0.45, 0.825},
    {0.525, 0.90},
    {0.6, 0.975},
};
```

This is a list of the 10 squares, each with a start and end percentage, indicating when each square should be visible.

And finally, a runnable example...

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Squares {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Squares();
    }

    public Squares() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private int runningTime = 5000;
        private long cycleStartedAt = -1;
        private double progress = 0;

        private double[][] squares = {
            {0, 0.30},
            {0.075, 0.375},
            {0.15, 0.45},
            {0.225, 0.525},
            {0.30, 0.60},

            {0.30, 0.675},
            {0.375, 0.75},
            {0.45, 0.825},
            {0.525, 0.90},
            {0.6, 0.975},
        };

        public TestPane() {
            Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (cycleStartedAt == -1) {
                        cycleStartedAt = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    }
                    long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - cycleStartedAt;
                    progress = (double)duration / (double)runningTime;
                    if (progress > 1.0d) {
                        cycleStartedAt = -1;
                        progress = 0;
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(true);
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int width = getWidth() - 1;
            int height = getHeight() - 1;

            int hGap = width / squares.length;
            int vGap = height / squares.length;

            int index = 0;
            for (double[] square : squares) {                
                if (progress >= square[0] && progress <= square[1]) {                    
                    int sWidth = hGap * (index + 1);
                    int sHeight = vGap * (index + 1);
                    int x = (width - sWidth) / 2;
                    int y = (height - sHeight) / 2;
                    g2d.drawRect(x, y, sWidth, sHeight);

                }
                index++;                
            }            
            g2d.dispose();
        }        
    }    
}
```

Check out [Performing custom painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) for more details